# Best way to make factor levels uniform over a number of data frames

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a number of data.frames that each have a factor.  I want to make sure that they all use the same levels.  What is the proper way to do this?

In the code below you'll see that I reassign the factor for each case using levels from the overall set of levels with a small convenience function changeLevels. I would expect that there is a better way to do this though.

```
set.seed(1234)
b<-round(runif(100,1,10),digits=2)
set.seed(2345)
b2<-round(runif(100,11,20),digits=2)
set.seed(3456)
b3<-round(runif(50,15,18),digits=2)

#.. all potential levels
bt<-factor(sort(c(b,b2,b3)))
lvls<-levels(bt)

t1<-as.data.frame(table(sample(b,5)))
t2<-as.data.frame(table(sample(b,1)))
t3<-as.data.frame(table(sample(b,1)))
t4<-as.data.frame(table(sample(b,8)))
t5<-as.data.frame(table(sample(b2,20)))
t6<-as.data.frame(table(sample(b3,18)))

t1<-cbind(t1,p="A")
t2<-cbind(t2,p="B")
t3<-cbind(t3,p="C")
t4<-cbind(t4,p="D")
t5<-cbind(t5,p="E")
t6<-cbind(t6,p="F")

d<-data.frame()
d<-rbind(d,t2,t3,t6,t4,t5,t1)

#.. out of order bins
ggplot(d,aes(x=factor(Var1),fill=factor(p))) +
  geom_bar(aes(weight=Freq)) +
  facet_grid( p ~ ., margins=T)+
  ggtitle("out of order bins")

changeFactor<-function(t,lvls){
  temp<-as.numeric(as.character(t))
  factor(temp,levels=lvls)
}

t1$Var1<-changeFactor(t1$Var1,lvls)
t2$Var1<-changeFactor(t2$Var1,lvls)
t3$Var1<-changeFactor(t3$Var1,lvls)
t4$Var1<-changeFactor(t4$Var1,lvls)
t5$Var1<-changeFactor(t5$Var1,lvls)
t6$Var1<-changeFactor(t6$Var1,lvls)

d<-data.frame()
d<-rbind(d,t2,t3,t6,t4,t5,t1)

#.. in order bins
ggplot(d,aes(x=factor(Var1),fill=factor(p))) +
  geom_bar(aes(weight=Freq)) +
  facet_grid( p ~ ., margins=T)+
  ggtitle("in order bins")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: keep your data in lists and learn the `*pply` family

```
set.seed(1234)
b<-round(runif(100,1,10),digits=2)
set.seed(2345)
b2<-round(runif(100,11,20),digits=2)
set.seed(3456)
b3<-round(runif(50,15,18),digits=2)

#.. all potential levels
bt<-factor(sort(c(b,b2,b3)))
lvls<-levels(bt)

options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
f <- function(x, y, z)
  cbind(data.frame(table(sample(x, y))), p = z)

datl <- Map(f, list(b,b,b,b,b2,b3), c(5,1,1,8,20,18), LETTERS[1:6])

changeFactor<-function(t,lvls){
  temp<-as.numeric(as.character(t))
  factor(temp,levels=lvls)
}

datl <- lapply(rapply(datl, f = function(x) changeFactor(x, lvls), 
                     classes = 'factor', how = 'replace'),
              data.frame)

d <- do.call(rbind, datl[c(2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 1)])

#.. in order bins
ggplot(d,aes(x=factor(Var1),fill=factor(p))) +
  geom_bar(aes(weight=Freq)) +
  facet_grid( p ~ ., margins=T)+
  ggtitle("in order bins")
```

[image]

long answer:

```
set.seed(1234)
b<-round(runif(100,1,10),digits=2)
set.seed(2345)
b2<-round(runif(100,11,20),digits=2)
set.seed(3456)
b3<-round(runif(50,15,18),digits=2)

#.. all potential levels
bt<-factor(sort(c(b,b2,b3)))
lvls<-levels(bt)
```

first, I don't want any unexpected factors popping up, so `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`
then write a function, f, to do what you want, and check to make sure it works

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
f <- function(x, y, z)
  cbind(data.frame(table(sample(x, y))), p = z)

f(b, 5, 'A')

#   Var1 Freq p
# 1 1.13    1 A
# 2 1.46    1 A
# 3 2.09    1 A
# 4  2.5    1 A
# 5 7.02    1 A
```

seems to work, so just `Map` it to lists of arguments and check the output

```
datl <- Map(f, list(b,b,b,b,b2,b3), c(5,1,1,8,20,18), LETTERS[1:6])

# List of 6
# $ :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Var1: Factor w/ 5 levels "2.02","3.09",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#   ..$ Freq: int [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
#   ..$ p   : chr [1:5] "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
# $ :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Var1: Factor w/ 1 level "1.63": 1
#   ..$ Freq: int 1
#   ..$ p   : chr "B"
```

so combine everything to use with ggplot

```
d <- do.call(rbind, datl[c(2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 1)])

library(ggplot2)
#.. out of order bins
ggplot(d,aes(x=factor(Var1),fill=factor(p))) +
  geom_bar(aes(weight=Freq)) +
  facet_grid( p ~ ., margins=T)+
  ggtitle("out of order bins")
```

[image]

```
changeFactor<-function(t,lvls){
  temp<-as.numeric(as.character(t))
  factor(temp,levels=lvls)
}
```

again making sure the function does what it is supposed to do on one data frame

```
changeFactor(datl[[1]]$Var1, lvls)

# [1] 2.02 3.09 3.79 3.89 8.3 
# 234 Levels: 1.09 1.12 1.13 1.24 1.36 1.38 1.41 1.46 1.63 1.66 1.81 1.95 ... 19.86
```

so apply it again to them all at once and check the output

```
datl <- lapply(rapply(datl, f = function(x) changeFactor(x, lvls), 
                     classes = 'factor', how = 'replace'),
              data.frame)
str(datl)
# List of 6
# $ :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Var1: Factor w/ 234 levels "1.09","1.12",..: 13 28 41 45 81
#   ..$ Freq: int [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
#   ..$ p   : chr [1:5] "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
# $ :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Var1: Factor w/ 234 levels "1.09","1.12",..: 9
#   ..$ Freq: int 1
#   ..$ p   : chr "B"
# ...
```

combine again and plot

```
d <- do.call(rbind, datl[c(2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 1)])

#.. in order bins
ggplot(d,aes(x=factor(Var1),fill=factor(p))) +
  geom_bar(aes(weight=Freq)) +
  facet_grid( p ~ ., margins=T)+
  ggtitle("in order bins")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly.  You use some functions I was unfamiliar with.

Comment: You use some functions I was unfamiliar with.  I realized after posting I could use the following:  d2$Var1<-unlist(tapply(d$Var1,d$p,function(dd) changeFactor(dd,lvls))) instead of some of the code.  My example was meant to be a simple case as my real problem involves extremely large data sets. Your comment regarding 'stringsAsFactors' is very important in this case.

Comment: @bob123: If your large datasets involve really large vectors of factors, be aware that the `stringsAsFactor = FALSE` option will make you manipulate very large vectors of *strings*, which are much heavier than the factors themselves (stored as simple integers in memory), especially if your levels have long names. If this was to be the case, you would better directly build your vectors as factors with the right levels, then use them as factors.

Answer (score 2):

I think your way "reading" the factors with `as.character` is the best way when you don't know all their "true" levels.

But since you *do* know them (they are all stored inside `lvls`), why not using them directly when you build your `ti$Var1` vectors? That is, instead of :

```
ti = as.data.frame(table(sample(b,5)));                 # automately creates a factor vector ti$Var1 with what is found inside the sample as levels
ti$Var1 = factor(as.character(ti$Var1), levels = lvls); # replaces it with a new factor, created by reading each value of the previous one and assigning it a level from lvls
```

(which is ultimately what you do),
do directly:

```
tab = table(sample(b,5));                         
ti = data.frame(myVar  = factor(names(tab), lvls)       # creates directly the right factor vector with levels drawn from lvls
              , myFreq = as.numeric(tab)
              );
```

(which is ultimately what you want) (and 'even allows you better control on the names of `ti`'s columns)

Or else, but you will then get empty lines:

```
factoredSample = factor(sample(b,5), lvls);             # directly associates each drawn value with a level from lvls
ti = as.data.frame(table(factoredSample));              # and table will then also count the non-represented levels within factoredSample
```

---

(By the way, I don't know whether or not this was only for asking-the-question purposes, but if you really have to handle so many almost-identical data.frames in your script, you are probably using the wrong data structure.)

Comment: @bob123: You're welcome. If these posts have provided everything you needed, you might consider now marking one answer as *accepted* so your question will be moved off the stack ;)